# How to delete gamer profiles from an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I can't figure out how to delete gamer profiles off my Xbox 360. I have a few profiles that were duplicates and some that aren't used. Is it possible to delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to **settings** and select **System**.
2. Select **Storage**
3. If you don’t connect any external storage devices to your console, select **Hard Drive**. If you do use external storage, instead select **All Devices**
4. Select **Profiles**
5. Select the profile that you want to delete.
6. Select **Delete**
7. Select one of the following:

   - **Delete Profile Only** - This deletes the profile but leaves saved games and achievements.
   - **Delete Profile and Items** - This deletes the profile and the associated saved games and achievements.

[**Source**](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/delete-xbox-live-profile-from-xbox-360-console)